# Can anyone help me to get the current category in my view.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9. I would like to get the current category of products in `app/design/frontend/xxxx/xxxx/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` file.
I've already tried `Mage::registry('current_category')` and `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()` for getting current category. I'm not getting any results from that. thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

Current Category's ID

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();?>
```

Current Category's Name

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();?>
```

Current Category's Parent's Id

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();?>
```

Comment: Glad to be of service. You could accept and upvote if you please

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
     $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category'); 
     if (isset($currentCat) ) { 
         $exp = explode("/", $currentCat->getPath());
     } else { 
         $exp = explode("/", '/1/0/10');
     }
 ?>
```

then example if you want to use it in body class for css modifications design:

```
<body class="cat-<?php echo $exp[2];?>
```

Comment: thank you..I tried your code, but i'm always getting the value "0" from $exp[2] for all categories

Comment: did you try modifying the number, example [1] ? im sharing you a code Im using. in this case, exp[2] displays the subcategory 2, eg: root_catalog/computers

Comment: and if you echo <?php echo $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>  only?

Comment: yes i tried all those. its only executing the else part and giving results like 1 or 0. Also tried echoing $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category'); and nothing come up

Answer (score 0):

you can get the category id from product name or id by loading model of product.

```
    $catCollection = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
    foreach($catCollection as $cat){
      print_r($cat->getData());
      //echo $cat->getName();
      //echo $cat->getUrl();
    }
```

Another Way,

```
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

After that you can get the categories by accessing $catIds array such as $catIds[0], $catIds[1] etc.